# SQLite accent-insensitive search

Tags: sqlite, qt, diacritics, sql-like, accent-insensitive

Is there any way to do an accent-insensitive LIKE query in SQLite? For example, this query:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE "Andre%"
```

would return:

```
André the Giant
Andre Agassi
etc.
```

I'm using Qt with QSqlDatabase if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up a [collation](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#collation) using [`sqlite3_create_collation`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_collation.html) and then use it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE "Andre%" COLLATE NOACCENTS
```

Comment: > How to setup sqlite3_create_collation in SQLite? Could you provide any link?

Comment: This is really a bad answer. It's not explaining anything I have no idea why someone market it as answered.