# accented chars in windows 8.1 embeded Sqlite

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-8, sqlite

I'm in a struggle with Sqlite and accented chars such as á or é.

What i'm trying to do is a select with where accent insensitive.

```
select * from customers where name like "%risque%"
```

in database

```
-> id =1; name=risqué 
-> id =2; name=risque second
```

d

the select return only record  **id =2 name=risque second**

i've tried:

```
select * from customers where name like "%risque%" COLLATE NOCASE
select * from customers where name like "%risque%" COLLATE NOACCENTS
```

Comment: Think you have to build your own, http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#collation  NO ACCENTS isn't listed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to ignore accent in SQLite query (Android)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16282083/how-to-ignore-accent-in-sqlite-query-android)

Comment: already read the article, tried everything and can not :(

Comment: COLLATE NOACCENTS [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14009261/sqlite-accent-insensitive-search?rq=1)