# Implementing accent insensitive search on django using sqlite

Tags: python, django, sqlite, python-2.7

This question is related to my earlier question [Accent insensitive search django sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31327019/accent-insensitive-search-django-sqlite)

As mentioned in the response there is no direct way to do so. I have come up with a solution, but I am not sure if it is a good one:

**Use Case**: Assume that the database has a table `NewsArticles` with one of the column being `ArticleText`. As the name implies `ArticleText` contains the text of the news articles which includes several words with accented characters. Let's say one such word present in the `ArticleText` for an article with Primary Key `aid123` is `Puerto Aisén`. Now, a user can search for either `Puerto Aisén` or `Puerto Aisen` and should be able to get the article with PK `aid123` back with the found accented word in bold (`<b>Puerto Aisén</b>`).

**Solution**: I add one more column in the table `normalizedArticleText` and make it contain the `unicode.normalize` (accent removed) version of the text. Now whenever a search query comes, I first determine if the query contains accented character or not by using `s.decode('ascii')` and then search accordingly in the corresponding column.

**Problem**: I am duplicating the whole data. Also, there is no way for me to bold the accented keyword if the search query was the non-accented version of the keyword.

Any brilliant suggestions? I am using django with sqlite

Answer (score -1):

Try using the unicodedata package. Here's an example for Python 3:

```
import unicodedata

unicodedata.normalize('NFD', 'répertoire').encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

Or, for Python 2.7:

```
import unicodedata

unicodedata.normalize('NFD', u'répertoire').encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

Either of these will output:

```
'repertoire'
```

Simply replace `répertoire` with your string. `NFD` is a `form` of normalization. You can read more on the different forms of normalization here:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize
https://docs.python.org/2/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize

Good luck!